# Getting a pattern to match consistently

Tags: regex

I'm using `.{0,70}(?:\\S(?:-| |$)|$)` to match the strings like `a/n b/n c/n` but only the last string is matched i.e `c`.

For example:

```
hello(newline)world(NL)java(NL)
```

only matches `java` but when i modify the regex to `.{0,70}(?:\\S(?:|-| |$)|$)` it works perfectly fine.Can any one explain this

Comment: I think you forgot to ask a question. :)

Comment: I've seen this question at least 2 times. Where in the world are you getting it ?

Comment: The 2nd one definitely doesn't do what you want. Having a `|` with nothing on one side allows the alternation to match nothing. Its unclear, at least to me, what you're trying to do though.

Comment: @OGHaza it matches a space `0x20` ?

Comment: @Hamza I mean that `(|x)` means match `x` or nothing.

Comment: @OGHaza eeeh lolwut, slipped my mind

Comment: @HamZa I knw that bt thats working in my case and that is only my question i.e how come the second expression mathches the whole string along with new line were as the first one only matches the last new line string

Comment: @user2531406 wow, so with `/n` you mean newline :O Dude, you're mixing everything up. To represent a newline use `\n`. Now why don't you write your **own** regex for **your** specific situation and **stop** ripping regex from the internetz ?

Answer (score 2):

Your second regex "works" because you added an empty alternative to the alternation, i.e. it went from `(a|b)` to `(a|b|)`, which will match at `a` or `b` or "nothing" (zero-width, it doesn't have to be a space character or anything, it will match between characters).

It doesn't work, but `.` matchs anything except newlines, and all your lines end in a non-whitespace character so `.{0,70}\S`+"nothing" will always match.

Your requirements are too unclear for me to give you a definitive answer (I'm not sure where the space and `-` in the alternation come into it). But if you're literally just trying to match whatever appears on a line I see no reason why you can't just use `.*\S` (which will give you the similar matches to your "working" regex). But if `.*\S` fulfills your needs you should probably just be splitting the string by the newline character and the right trimming it.

Comment: Could it be our confused OP is looking for the Single Line Modifier, whatever it is in the as yet to be named programming language? (OP: "regex" is *not* a programming language per se.)